# How do I display number of WooCommerce products tags in frontend?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to print out the total number of products tags from WooCommerce in the front end.

Like:

We have products from __ different brands.

*where '__' is the number of product tags.*

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to accomplish this, however I find one of the easiest is to use something like the following:

```
<?php

$term_count = wp_count_terms('pa_brand');

echo sprintf('We have products from %d different brands', $term_count);

?>
```

Where `brand` in `pa_brand` is the slug of the WooCommerce attribute you wish to count. This works because WooCommerce creates a custom taxonomy for every product attribute with a name prefix of `pa_`.

As you mentioned in the comments you wish to get a count of the `product_tag` taxonomy, so you could do that by using:

```
<?php

$term_count = wp_count_terms('product_tag');

echo sprintf('We have products from %d different brands', $term_count);

?>
```

Comment: simple and good answer, but also include the link of the `wp_count_terms()` for further reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How do I find out which slug WooCommerce uses for product tags?

Comment: Go into **Products -> Attributes** and in the table there is a column for **slug**, use that to identify the slug you wish to use.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstand me. I do not want to count an attribute like "color" or "size", but the "product tag" which I use for brands.

Comment: If that is the case, product_tag is a taxonomy so use `wp_count_terms('product_tag')` and it will give you the correct result. If this works please mark it as the correct answer.